# Testing an Angular Controller that uses Datatables - mocking DTOptionsBuilder and DT ColumnBuilder

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, datatable, jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for an Angular controller that mostly creates a datatable of values from the server. I've tried mocking DTOptionsBuilder and DTColumnBuilder but this doesn't seem to work. I get the error:

'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function(){
            return MarketsFactory.getAll();
        })
            .withDataProp')

Here is the Controller code:

```
.controller('MarketsCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $state, MarketsFactory, 

DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

    $scope.edit = function(data){
        $state.go('admin.market', {id:data});
    };

    //DATATABLES CONFIGURATIONS

    $scope.dtInstance = {};

  $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function(){
        return MarketsFactory.getAll();
    })
        .withDataProp('data.data')
        .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
       $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
        .withTableTools('http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')
    .withTableToolsButtons([
        'copy',
        'print', {
            'sExtends': 'collection',
            'sButtonText': 'Save',
            'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
        }
    ])
    .withBootstrap()
    .withBootstrapOptions({
      TableTools: {
        classes: {
          container: 'btn-group right',
          buttons: {
              normal: 'btn btn-outline btn-default btn-sm'
          }
        }
     }
   });

    $scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('shortName').withTitle('Short Name').withClass('dt-left'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('Name').withClass('dt-left'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('timezone').withTitle('Time Zone').withClass('dt-left'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
        return '<a ng-click="edit(\'' + data + '\')">Edit</a>';
    })];
    })
```

And the test file:

```
describe('Controller: MarketsCtrl', function () {
  var scope, $state, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder;

  beforeEach(function(){
    var mockState = {};
    var mockDTOptionsBuilder = {};
    var mockDTColumnBuilder = {};

    module('app', function($provide) {
      $provide.value('$state', mockState);
      $provide.value('DTOptionsBuilder', mockDTOptionsBuilder);
      $provide.value('DTColumnBuilder', mockDTColumnBuilder);
    });

    inject(function() {

      mockState.go = function(target) {
        return target;
      };

      mockDTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise = jasmine.createSpy('DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise');
      mockDTOptionsBuilder.withDataProp = jasmine.createSpy('DTOptionsBuilder.withDataProp');

      mockDTColumnBuilder.newColumn = jasmine.createSpy('DTColumnBuilder.newColumn');

    });

  });

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$state_, _DTColumnBuilder_, _DTOptionsBuilder_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $state = _$state_;
    DTOptionsBuilder = _DTOptionsBuilder_;
    DTColumnBuilder = _DTColumnBuilder_;

    $controller('MarketsCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      $state: $state,
      DTOptionsBuilder: DTOptionsBuilder,
      DTColumnBuilder: DTColumnBuilder
    });

    scope.$digest();
  }));


  it('should provide an edit function', function () {
    expect(typeof scope.edit).toBe('function');
  });


});
```

I thought that creating a mock and putting a Spy on it would prevent it from calling the chained functions, but I guess not.

I'm quite new to testing, especially with Angular, so any help in general would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*I'm approaching this from a [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org)/[mocha](http://mochajs.org) background*

I'm having some trouble decrypting your beforeEach block - but it can be simplified to some extent:

```
var $scope, $state, DTColumnBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder, createController;

beforeEach(function () {
  DTColumnBuilder  = {};
  DTOptionsBuilder = {};
  $state           = {};

  module('app', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('$state', $state);
    $provide.value('DTColumnBuilder', DTColumnBuilder);
    $provide.value('DTOptionsBuilder', DTOptionsBuilder);
  });

  inject(function ($controller, $injector) {
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    $state = $injector.get('$state');
    DTColumnBuilder  = $injector.get('DTColumnBuilder');
    DTOptionsBuilder = $injector.get('DTOptionsBuilder');

    createController = function () {
      return $controller('MarketsCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $state: $state,
        DTOptionsBuilder: DTOptionsBuilder,
        DTColumnBuilder: DTColumnBuilder        
      });
    }
  });

  // Stub out the methods of interest. 
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise = angular.noop;
  $state.go = function () { console.log('I tried to go but.... I cant!!');
  DTColumnBuilder.bar = function () { return 'bar'; };
});
```

---

The nature of a `spy` is that of letting the original implementation do its thing, but *recording* all of the calls to said function and an assortment of associated data.

A `stub` on the other hand is a `spy` with an extended API where you can completely modify the workings of said function. Return value, expected parameters, etc etc.

Assuming we used the aforementioned beforeEach block, `DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise` would be a `noop` at this point. As such it would be safe to `spy` on it and expect the method to have been called.

```
it('should have been called', function () {
  var spy = spyOn(DTOPtionsBuilder, 'fromFnPromise');
  createController();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If you wanted to manipulate the return value of said function, I would grab [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org) and make it a `stub`.

```
it('became "foo"', function () {
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise = sinon.stub().returns('foo');
  createController();
  expect($scope.dtOptions).toEqual('foo');
});
```

Now, since you are working with promises it's a wee bit more complicated but the basics of stubbing out a promise based function would be to:

- Inject `$q` into your spec file.
- Tell the `stub` to return `$q.when(/** value **/)` in the case of a **resolved promise.**
- Tell the `stub` to return `$q.reject(/** err **/)` in the case of a **rejected promise.**
- Run `$timeout.flush()` to flush all deferred tasks.
- *Trigger the `done` callback to notify Jasmine that you are done waiting for async tasks (may not be needed). This depends on the test framework/runner.*

It *could* look something like so:

```
it('resolves with "foo"', function (done) {
  DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise = sinon.stub().returns($q.when('foo'));
  expect($scope.options).to.eventually.become('foo').and.notify(done); // this is taken from the chai-as-promised library, I'm not sure what the Jasmine equivalent would be (if there is one).
  createController();
  $timeout.flush();
});
```

---

Now, a lot of this is just guesswork at this point. It's quite hard to set up a fully working test suite without having the source code running right beside me for cross reference, but I hope this will at least give you some ideas of how to get going with your spies and stubs.